# The lighting of one of the pillars in my compositing render has a black box and a dark line, but the viewport render doesn’t (cyclesrender)

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, shaders, compositing-nodes

so for some reason in my animation the top of the pillar is black, but the top isn’t the only part. The bottom has messed up lighting and doesn’t match the environment. Also at the top again with the black boxes, behind the pillars there’s a dark line for some reason. Can someone help?
[image]

This is composite[image]
This is viewport

Comment: Hello hard to tell, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Maybe some object set hidden in the viewport, but not in the render, casting a shadow?